# From review is not specified in comment done in review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Yesterday I came to review one answer in the *First Posts* review queue. This is the link to that review [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20189888).

I have seen many times that when someone comments on a question or answer while reviewing then the comment is prefixed by **From Review:**. I commented on the respected given review what I felt was appropriate for that review. But the comment was applied as a normal comment without the prefix **From Review**.

When I checked as I normally view my previous comments, if someone replied to my comments without tagging, I came to know that it was just a normal comment with two upvotes. I would like to know that is the intended behavior on Stack Overflow or am I missing some criteria so as to get that prefix? Or is it a bug or there is some privilege to get so, or it might be restricted to some queues only?

Can anyone shed some light on this? I would like to know how this works.

Comment: I find the title incomprehensible: *From review is not specified in comment done in review queue*. Can you elaborate?

Comment: can you suggest a more comprehensible title? @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment appended with *review link* and text **From Review** is displayed when you choose the available reasons in the dialog, for example, in the low-quality queue.

[image]

Choosing any reason other than no comment needed would complete the action as well as add the comment with the review link. There is no such action/dialog in the first post review queue.

You could manually set the review link in your custom comment that you add to the review if you find it necessary.

If a reviewer were to directly comment on the post, there is no link appended. This is expected behavior.